# How to add 10 numbers to a ListBox with less code?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I coded this. It's fine but can I write it with less code?

```
    If D = 10 Then
        ListBox3.Items.Add(1)
        ListBox3.Items.Add(2)
        ListBox3.Items.Add(3)
        ListBox3.Items.Add(4)
        ListBox3.Items.Add(5)
        ListBox3.Items.Add(6)
        ListBox3.Items.Add(7)
        ListBox3.Items.Add(8)
        ListBox3.Items.Add(9)
        ListBox3.Items.Add(10)
    End If
```

if you don't understand my question you can read the following example:

We can code

```
 Dim A As Integer
 Dim B As Integer
 Dim C As Integer
 Dim D As Integer
```

but we can code it in a more concise way like this

```
Dim A, B, C, D As Integer
```

Comment: `ListBox3.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Cast(Of Object).ToArray))`

Comment: See: [Loop Structures (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezk76t25.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [stackoverflow Documentation "For ... Next"](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vb.net/1639/looping/5296/for-next#t=201608061516422319054)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a For Loop:

```
    For i As Integer = 1 To 10
        ListBox3.Items.Add(i)
    Next
```